# Javascript this.href from asp.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How do I pass this.href from asp.net code behind? Here is what I have, and in javascript I added a alert to see the value and it says 'undefined'

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Sample", "Callscript(this.href);", true);

function Callscript(href) 
{
    alert(href);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href` is not a property of the global object. i believe you are looking for `window.location.href`:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Sample", "Callscript(window.location.href);", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the href from aspx.cs file properly. It should be something like below.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Sample", "Callscript('" + this.href + "');", true);  

function Callscript(href)  
{     
    alert(href); 
}
```

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

"This" is two different things - it's one thing on the server and another on the client.

You may try modifying your startup script like so:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Sample", "Callscript('" + this.href + "');", true);
```